# Argument of length 0 error

Tags: r

I have two data frames (**eeg** and **p1_1_a**). They look like this:

```
> head(eeg)
  wave_1
1 18.959
2 19.432
3 20.384
4 20.489
5 21.012
6 21.571

> nrow(eeg)
[1] 849

> class(eeg$wave_1)
[1] "numeric"

> head(p1_1_a)
      Time  Latency Amplitude Peak_Lenght
1  57.1184  7.90738 -0.388889     8.44690
2 123.3470 15.49230 -0.917778     5.51634
3 191.0920 11.87220 -0.466667     6.55066
4 249.1710 15.49230 -0.871111     5.68873
5 325.5090 10.32080 -0.388889     5.34396
6 385.6040 12.56180 -0.684444     4.82680

> class(p1_1_a$Time)
[1] "numeric"

> nrow(p1_1_a)
[1] 10
```

I want to create a list consisting of the number from wave_1 that are the closest smaller numbers to each of the numbers in Time. So the list will be of 10 numbers and the first one will be 56.678 (wave_1[48]) as this is the closest smaller number to Time[1] (57.1184). I have written a loop:

```
list <- c()

for(i in 1:nrow(p1_1_a$Time)){
if(eeg$wave_1 <= p1_1_a$Time[i]){
  list <- max(eeg$wave_1[eeg$wave_1 <= p1_1_a$Time[i]])
  }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in 1:nrow(p1_1_a$Time) : argument of length 0
```

I have tried searching the web for an answer but I just cannot figure this out. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the rest of your code, but `p1_1_a$Time` is a vector, not matrix, so you cannot do `nrow()`. Try `length(p1_1_a$Time)`